# Как вывести значение колонок с названием полей?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Как вывести значение колонок вместе с названием полей с помощью библиотеки pymysql?

| Один | Два | Три |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Используя запрос `SELECT * FROM table` вывод `(('1','2','3')`, необходимо конвертировать в `('Один:'1','Два':'2','Три':'3')`

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table'")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достать значения колонок можно из аттрибута `description` в курсоре. Оно хранит список: один элемент для одной колонки.

Получить словари с именем колонки в качестве ключа можно приблизительно так:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table'")
rows = cur.fetchall()
# в первом элементе хранится имя колонки
column_names = [d[0] for d in cur.description]
for row in rows:
    row_dict = {column_names[index]:value for (index, value) in enumerate(row)}
    print(row_dict)
```